# How did they make this ? using Flash or what?

Tags: javascript, css, flash

http://uk.lifestyle.yahoo.com/

This thing that's got links like "Five ways to achieve..,Food and diet terms..,etc"..when u hover over links images are displayed..

Any other way to make this thing if it's Flash only?

Comment: I see you want to do something in Flash. You need to totally drop that and start using jQuery.

Comment: Let me introduce you to my friend, Mr. View Source.

Comment: (Actually @Pekka I think he/she does *not* want to make something with Flash.)

Comment: oh ok..why's that Play/Pause button then? thot it was Flash stuff

Comment: @Pointy..um I actually did try and inspect that element but couldn't find the css class :/

Comment: Because constantly transitioning carousels are annoying for some people, so they let you stop the animation.

Comment: @Pointy..ur right..don't wanna use Flash..what's that thing called in Jquery btw?? wanna try that..like what do I search for?

Comment: There's no such thing as "a css class". The element will be build of some HTML, with a bunch of CSS rule-sets and some JavaScript.

Comment: Pekka, I see you shoot from the hip when you see a technology you don't like mentioned, and even disregard reading the question. You need to stop that and instead get into the spirit of SO and help fellow developers with their questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is JavaScript image rotator there are plenty of them online

examples:

http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/
http://www.sohtanaka.com/web-design/examples/image-rotator/
http://css-tricks.com/examples/FeaturedContentSlider/
http://www.twospy.com/galleriffic/example-2.html

You can use [jQuery](http://jquery.com), CSS and HTML to create same effects

Answer (score 7):

It's a combination of HTML, CSS, and Yahoo's YUI Javascript library. No Flash required.  :)